# TypeError: undefined not a constructor when using beforeEach in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have run into a problem when writing unit tests in jasmine which I have managed to distill down to a a very basic test scenario:

```
describe('weird shit', function () {
    var myVal;
    beforeEach(myVal = 0);
    it('throws for some reason', function () {
        expect(myVal).toBe(0);
    });
});
```

and this throws a TypeError:

```
Test 'weird shit:throws for some reason' failed
    TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'queueableFn.fn.call(self.userContext)') in 

file:///C:/USERS/9200378/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/14.0/EXTENSIONS/SKJV5WFA.151/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js (line 1886)
    run@file:///C:/USERS/9200378/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/14.0/EXTENSIONS/SKJV5WFA.151/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1874:20
    execute@file:///C:/USERS/9200378/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/14.0/EXTENSIONS/SKJV5WFA.151/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:1859:13
    queueRunnerFactory@file:///C:/USERS/9200378/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/14.0/EXTENSIONS/SKJV5WFA.151/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:697:42
    execute@file:///C:/USERS/9200378/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/14.0/EXTENSIONS/SKJV5WFA.151/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:359:28
    fn@file:///C:/USERS/9200378/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/14.0/EXTENSIONS/SKJV5WFA.151/TestFiles/jasmine/v2/jasmine.js:2479:44
```

if I removed the `beforeEach` then it works fine:

```
describe('weird shit', function () {
    var myVal =0;
    it('throws for some reason', function () {
        expect(myVal).toBe(0);
    });
});
```

Which I do not understand, the `beforeEach` is very basic, please help.

Answer (score 3):

`beforeEach` accepts a function, you passed the result of `myVal = 0`, which is `0`, which isn't a function.

```
beforeEach(myVal = 0);
```

Replace the above code with the following:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  myVal = 0;
});
```

Refer the documentation of jasmine 2.5 [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(function(){myVal = 0;});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of beforeEach() is to execute some function that contains code to setup your specs.

In this case, it is setting variable `myVal = 0`

You should pass a function to beforeEach() like below:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  myVal = 0
});
```

in order to successfully setup your variable.